# Force Cortex-M3/4 reset from assembly

Tags: stm32, assembly, cortex-m3, cortex-m

I would like to force my STM32F4 to reset on fault, I tried to copy NVIC_SystemReset in assembly as :

```
    .section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
    Default_Handler:
        dsb
        ldr     r0, =0xE000ED0C
        ldr     r1, =0x05FA0007
        str     r1, [r0, #0]
        dsb
    Infinite_Loop:
        b  Infinite_Loop
    .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
```

But it does not reset, the program simply hangs. Is it because Default_Handler is an interrupt ? Did I miss the obvious ?

NVIC_SystemReset works fine in user space.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting bit 2 (SYSRESETREQ) of the AIRCR resgister to force a reset of all systems but the debug logic. However, you need to allow writing to the register, writing 0x5FA to VECTKEY, otherwise the write is ignored. But you are doing that. Hmmm.

Try writing 0X05FA0004

From the ST manual:

Bit 1 VECTCLRACTIVE
Reserved for Debug use. This bit reads as 0. When writing to the register you must write 0 to
this bit, otherwise behavior is unpredictable.
Bit 0 VECTRESET
Reserved for Debug use. This bit reads as 0. When writing to the register you must write 0 to
this bit, otherwise behavior is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this is the issue, but I noticed in the c-code that in the core_cm#.h implementations of NVIC_SystemReset the firmware maintains the state of the PRIGROUP BITS:

```
SCB->AIRCR = ((0x5FA << SCB_AIRCR_VECTKEY_Pos) | (SCB->AIRCR & SCB_AIRCR_PRIGROUP_Msk) | SCB_AIRCR_SYSRESETREQ_Msk); /* Keep priority group unchanged */
```

(see http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CIHFDJCA.html)

Writing the word 0X05FA0004 blindly does not do that and has caused me problems with my own implementations of the soft reset in the past on the stm32f4.

Reading in the previous state in order to maintain the state of those PRIGROUP bits in your reset word may solve the problem.